# Compute $ \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} e^{A\tau}G \,Q\, {(e^{A\tau}G)}^T \, d\tau$, where $A, G, Q$ are constant matrices, independent of $\tau$

Tags: integration, matrix-calculus

how to integrate this matrix:
$$
\int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}}  e^{A\tau}G \,Q\, {(e^{A\tau}G)}^T  \, d\tau, \quad t_{k+1} -t_k = \Delta t , \text{ A, G, Q are const matrixs, independent of $\tau$}
$$

In [wiki/Matrix_calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), i only found how to calculate partial derivatives, is there some recommended books to calculate this integral, thanks in advance!

Edit(2020/04/20):
Sorry, i didn't give more details, thanks @Daniel and @Ninad for your replys. I met this equation in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.00036) to calculate the discrete time noise  covariance, [the spapshot of the eq2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D9ex.png)

- The $Q$ is continuous time noise covariance
  matrix of the system, it is symmetic.
- Here $A$ is the $\Phi({t_{k+1}, \tau})$ of the paper, it is a square matrix. BTW, $F$ matrix size in the eq2. of the paper should be $21*21$.
- $G$ size is 21*12, $Q$ size is 12*12.

I think Ninad's solution seems correct.

Comment: the first step is to rewrite $e^{A \tau} = \sum (A \tau)^n/n!$ ?

Answer (score 1):

First rewrite the integral as

$$\int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} e^{A\tau}Ke^{A^T\tau}\:d\tau$$

where we denote

$$K = GQG^T$$

Now use the substitution $X = e^{A^T\tau} \implies dX = A^T e^{A^T\tau}d\tau$

$$\int_{X_k}^{X_{k+1}}X^TKA^{-T}dX$$

$A^{-T}$ commutes with $X$ so we can pull it out of the integral. If we make the assumption that $Q$ is symmetric then we have that the integral equals

$$=\frac{1}{2}X^TKXA^{-T}\Biggr|_{X_k}^{X_{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2}e^{A\tau}Ke^{A^T\tau}A^{-T}\Biggr|_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{At_{k+1}}Ke^{A^Tt_{k+1}} - e^{At_k}Ke^{A^Tt_k}\right)A^{-T}$$

if $Q$ is not symmetric then this is not integrable in this way, and diagonalizing $A$ would be the way to go, if it is possible.

Comment: This is the first time I've attempted such an operation, it seems an unusual thing to ask for an analytic answer as opposed to integrating term by term. If this is not correct let me know.

Comment: Hi Ninad, how do you calculate the last integral $\int_{X_{k}}^{X_{k+1}} X^{T} K A^{-T} d X$?  When we calculate $X^T KX A^{-T}$ , which is a matrix, derivatives with respect to $X$, $X$ is a square matrix, how to calculate a matrix drivatives to a matrix, i want to figure out how you get the integral result. In [wiki:Derivatives_with_matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_matrices), it doesn't involved. Could you please suggest some reference book or paper, thanks very much!

Comment: I think it would be better to take the derivative of the antiderivative derived and show that it's derivative is indeed the expression we started with. Anything up until that step is just a mnemonic, even the substitution.

Comment: why the result is not
$\int_{X_{k}}^{X_{k+1}} X^{T} K A^{-T} d X$ = $\int_{X_{k}}^{X_{k+1}} X^{T} d X \cdot K A^{-T}$ =$\frac{1}{2} trace(X^TX) |_{X_k}^{X_{k+1}} \cdot K A^{-T}$, because$K,A$ are const matrixs, we can pull them out of the integral, am i correct?